# Sending an automated SMS before switching off the phone

Tags: sms, automation

Can I send an automated SMS to any specific number by an application/service (which I set ON), if phone gets switched off before closing that service or application?
Also can I do the same if phone breaks down in an accident or if I do specific action on phone, such as "Tap the screen 3 times while phone's screen is locked", or "shake the phone 3 times while it is locked"?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at tasker?https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm

Answer (score 1):

Tasker should do the first things you asked about, but I doubt you'll find anything that can recognize "Tap the screen 3 times while phone's screen is locked" or "shake the phone 3 times while it is locked", short of writing a custom app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en

Tasker is a great app in general that you really should check out since it sounds like you want to do a lot of automation type stuff.

Comment: While agreeing on the "tap while locked" (especially when the screen is off), *Tasker* should be able to handle the "shake" stuff fine (except if the device turns the sensors off when screen is shut off). Difficulty here, however, might be the special shake-pattern (which *Tasker* AFAIK does not support itself); maybe some addon is available which could realize even that. Btw: Free trial of *Tasker* avaialable on their homepage. It's worth every cent to buy it, when you find you can deal with it. You just have to get used to it ;)